# Group by time interval with count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have built the following query:

```
select CALL_RESULT, val from (
SELECT CALL_RESULT,
  TO_CHAR (
    FROM_TZ (
      CAST (DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60) * CALL_TIME AS TIMESTAMP),
      'UTC')
    AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific/Auckland',
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as val 
FROM WI_TABLE_1 
) where val >= '12/10/2018' group by CALL_RESULT, val;
```

It outputs the following data:

```
CALL_RESULT    VAL
8              12/10/2018 10:11:49
8              12/10/2018 10:15:56
8              12/10/2018 09:24:02
8              12/10/2018 09:24:14
8              12/10/2018 10:11:25
8              12/10/2018 10:12:01
8              12/10/2018 10:14:24
11             12/10/2018 09:20:47
11             12/10/2018 09:18:12
11             12/10/2018 09:18:30
11             12/10/2018 09:18:45
11             12/10/2018 09:18:46
...            ....
```

I am trying now to count the different CALL_RESULT, but groupe by time interval of 15 minutes.
I have tried everything I could think of but did not succeed. Is there an Oracle wizard that could help me out?

This idea would be:

```
CALL_RESULT    INTERVAL              COUNT
8              10:00                 3
11             10:00                 1
8              10:15                 3
11             10:30                 0
8              10:30                 3
...            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the results of your first query, You'll want to do something like

```
select callresult, count(0)
from table
group by datepart(minute, val) / 15
```

grouping by integer rounding on the minute of the date will give you groups of 15 minutes to operate on in the data above

Comment: needs 2 columns `callresult, datepart(minute, val) / 15 interval` in select and group by clauses

Comment: Yeah my idea is to give the premise of the answer for aur8l to work off

Comment: Downvoting this, for several reasons. First, there is no `datepart` in Oracle. (The post is clearly tagged with the requested SQL dialect.) Second, dividing the minutes by 15 still doesn't group by anything (unless you work in some db product where integer division truncates the fractional part; I am aware of no such db product). Then, even if that was correct, you are mixing together things from the first quarter-hour (say) from **different** hours. These are mistakes in your thinking, not "for so-and-so to work off." Post correct answers, or expect downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If there are "gaps" in the source data, and you need every interval to be present in the result (e.g. might be needed for graphing) then you need to generate a set of intervals to cover the wanted time period. Now, again, there are several techniques for this but below is a way that is common for many databases including Oracle 11g (a "recursive common table expression). This example generates 96 15 minute time intervals (enough for a single day):

```
with cte (n) as (
    select 0 as n from dual

    union all

    select n + 15 from cte
    where n < (24*60)
    )
select
      dt + n/1440 as dt_from
    , dt + (n+15)/1440 as dt_to
from cte
cross join (select to_date('2018-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd') as dt from dual)
```

The result of that would look like this (dd.mm.yyyy):

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|    |       DT_FROM       |        DT_TO        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 10.12.2018 00:00:00 | 10.12.2018 00:15:00 |
|  2 | 10.12.2018 00:15:00 | 10.12.2018 00:30:00 |
...
| 95 | 10.12.2018 23:30:00 | 10.12.2018 23:45:00 |
| 96 | 10.12.2018 23:45:00 | 11.12.2018 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

There are other Oracle specific ways to generate rows notable `connect by level` you can can research.

Once you have a needed set of intervals, left join your data to this, and group e.g.

```
with cte (n) as (
    select 0 as n from dual

    union all

    select n + 15 from cte
    where n < (24*60)-15
    )
select 
     d.CALL_RESULT, r.dt_from, count(d.val)
from (
    select
          cj.dt + n/1440 as dt_from
        , cj.dt + (n+15)/1440 as dt_to
    from cte
    cross join (select to_date('2018-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd') as dt from dual) cj
    ) r
left join (
        SELECT CALL_RESULT
         , val
        FROM (
         SELECT CALL_RESULT
          , TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1 / 24 / 60 / 60) * CALL_TIME AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific/Auckland', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS val
         FROM WI_TABLE_1
         )
        WHERE val >= '12/10/2018'
        GROUP BY CALL_RESULT
         , val
    ) d on d.val >= r.dt_from and d.val < r.dt_to
group by 
     d.CALL_RESULT, r.dt_from
```

Comment: Sounds like where I should be going. However, Oracle 10g in this instance so cte will not be an option. However, you gave me food for thoughts. Appreciate it.

Comment: search tip: `connect by`  e.g. `select rownum r from dual 
connect by rownum <= 10`  just substitute the method that produces the needed rows.